# Installing stringi repeatedly fails

Tags: r, stringi

I am trying to install likert, which requires stringi.

`install.package("likert")` fails to install stringi.

`install.package("stringi")` from CRAN fails as well:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/stringi_1.7.6.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 14390020 bytes (13.7 MB)
==================================
downloaded 9.3 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 9800943 != reported length 14390020
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/stringi_1.7.6.tgz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/stringi_1.7.6.tgz' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘stringi’ failed
```

I downloaded the package from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html and tried installing:
`install.packages("~/Desktop/downloads/stringi_1.7.6.tgz", repos = NULL, type = .Platform$pkgType)`

But this also failed:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringi’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What is going on? I have the latest version of R and R Studio for Mac.

Comment: Maybe try using `install.packages("stringi")` again as it looks like there was an error during download. Maybe try another CRAN-Mirror if this sill is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. The problem was the timeout. It took too long to load.
I fixed it by changing the timeout from 60seconds to a larger number:

```
getOption('timeout')
[1] 60
options(timeout=300)
```